# Not able to execute Rspec inside module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am getting error while executing rspec for a controller(controller is inside a module).

Controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    require 'unirest'
    require 'json'

    class CallRecordsController < ApplicationController
    //codes
    end
   end
end
```

rspec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::CallrecordsController, :type => :controller do
//code
end
```

Error:

```
in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Api::V1 (NameError)
```

i am a fresher i am not familiar with Rspec, waiting for your valuable informations

Comment: show your folder structure..

Comment: do you have a directory path like `<app_root_dir_>/spec/controllers/api/v1/callrecords_controller_spec.rb` ?

Comment: So, that's the mistake.. Do that!

Comment: i created that path and tried,but still i am getting same error  thanks for your valuable comment

Comment: Your Rspec version ?

Comment: gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'

Comment: I believe the `spec/` subdirectory is not as important as the location of actual production code. What is the path to your controller? Is it `$RAILS_ROOT/api/v1/call_records_controller.rb`?

Comment: no,  $RAILS_ROOT/controller/api/call_records_controller.rb   its my controller path